# Too many columns in Table

Tags: jquery, python, django, datatables

I think this is design issue, though it may be turned into a technical issue eventually.

I am working on a management website, on where I often need to render a table to user for viewing. I use JQuery.DataTable for rendering the data, which works fine.

The issue is that my tables usually contain more than a dozen columns, which seems fine, but sometime it will be a disaster to render them on a single table. The page will be stretched too wide and user need to scroll left to right to see all the info.

I am thinking that this should be a frequent issue for most management console developer and there must be standard workaround for this. BTW, removing any exist columns from table is not a option.

The only direction I may work on is to hide some columns and only show them under the trigger of clicking a button or hovering some elements. I am not sure Jquery.dataTable support this kind of thing. I can build it, but it takes time.

So I need some advice from your guys before I go crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the Table into a container with

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

This will make your table not to stretch the website.

With some nice css you can make the table container look awesome AND functional.

You can also add manual buttons to move the table left/right in the container, 
to view every column the user might be interested in.
(the container should have 'position:relative' and the table 'position:absolute' - then change the 'left' parameter)

Comment: I find some useful options in DataTable, which is similar to what you suggest. I didn't use your approach entirely, but you advice is a hint. Thanks!

Comment: @JerryMeng can you provide the found options in datatables?